# Pipelines в scikit. Построение алгоритма

Tags: python, алгоритм, машинное-обучение, scikit-learn

Вопрос про `pipelines` из `scikit-learn`. Есть `PolynomialFeatures()`, `PCA()` и `LogReg()`. Есть обучающая выборка `x_train, y_train` и тестовая `x_test, y_test`. Через `x, y` обозначу `union(x_test, x_train)` и union(y_test, y_train) соответственно. Хочу сделать следующий финт ушами:

Закинуть в `x_poly = PolynomialFeatures(x_train)`. Применить к ним `x_pca = PCA(x_poly)` с понижением размерности. Затем объединить `x_union = concatenate(x_train, x_pca, axis=1)`. И поклассифицировать их через `LogReg()`.

Вопросы.

- У `pipeline` есть метод `fit(X, [y])`. Я так понимаю, что `[y]`используется лишь в том случае, если он есть у соответствующего алгоритма. Т.е. в `PCA.fit()` y не будет использоваться, а в `LogReg().fit()` будет использоваться.

  - Каким образом разрешится вопрос с `PolynomialFeatures()`, ведь у  этого объекта, метод `fit()` имеет 2 аргумента: `fit(X, y=None)`?
  - Что здесь обозначает y в документации?
  - В каких случаях, всё-таки, будет использоваться y в алгоритмах, присутствующих в pipeline, а в каких -- нет?
- Мне нужно объединить `x_pca` с `x_train`. Как это сделать, если непосредственно `numpy` использовать нельзя? Если можно использовать `numpy`, то как?
- Можно ли в `pipeline` использовать условия. Например. Дойдя до определённой стадии алгоритма. Скажем, до `PCA()`. Я считаю дисперсию по максимальной компоненте. Если она `> 0.5`, то я использую `logReg()`. Если меньше, то я использую `SVM()`. Есть ли возможность реализовать такой функционал?

Comment: Случайно не знаете в scikit-learn как то можно реализовать рекуррентную нейронную сеть (RNN) ?

Comment: @ИгорьИгоряныч А что насчёт гугления: http://www.kdnuggets.com/2016/02/scikit-flow-easy-deep-learning-tensorflow-scikit-learn.html . Вторая ж ссылка по запросу `scikit learn recurrent neural network`

Comment: я уже весь интернет перегуглил, а та ссылка что ты дал это реализация не на scikit-learn а на tensorflow и то не RNN

Comment: @ИгорьИгоряныч там микс. Почему нужно именно scikit? Есть чудесный keras

Comment: Все реализации которые связаны с машинным обучением у меня на scikit, не хочу от него отходить

Comment: @ИгорьИгоряныч по-моему Вы выбираете плохую стратегию. Не стоит ударятся во что-то одно и использовать это всего и везде. Да, бывают исключения: это касается уникальных вещей. Но scikit не реализует достаточно хорошо NN. Для чего изобретать велосипед и выстреливать себе в ногу? Для Ваших целей есть другие, очень хорошие инструменты.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Для того, чтобы понять, что происходит в PCA и PolynomialFeatures, необходимо заглянуть в [код](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/ef5cb84a/sklearn/decomposition/pca.py#L327). `y` там не используется. 
  `y=None` нужно для того чтобы сигнатура была общая у всех методов `pipeline` , а `None` дефолтное значение.
- Для объединения фич можно использовать [FeatureUnion](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/plot_feature_stacker.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-plot-feature-stacker-py). Данный объект легко объединяется с pipeline. Кроме того, стоить принять во внимание, что понадобится использовать ItemSelector, про который сказано [тут](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/177082/sklearn-combine-multiple-feature-sets-in-pipeline). Также стоит принять во внимание [этот ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31259891/put-customized-functions-in-sklearn-pipeline).
- На последний вопрос ответить однозначно не удалось:

  > не уверен насколько это хорошая идея. А что если у вас для train и test sets будут разные значения дисперсии и соответственно разные алгоритмы?